# SQL Server : problem updating a counter type column in a table. All rows get the same value and they should not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and looking for assistance updating every record in a table column with a calculated value. I'm sure I am overthinking this!

I need to loop through all the records (870K+) and increment a counter variable with a value between 01 and 99 (2 digits) which will replace the value in the `MemoKeyExtension` (NChar 2) column in my table.

To keep it simple, you can assume this table just has a `uniqueid` column, an `account number` column (int), and the `MemoKeyExtension` (nChar2) column.

```
DECLARE @COUNT as Int
SET @COUNT = 0

DECLARE Mem_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT MemoKeyExtension FROM Customer.Memo
OPEN MEM_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MEM_Cursor 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    IF @COUNT < 99
        BEGIN
        SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
        SET @COUNT = 1
        END

        UPDATE Customer.Memo
        SET MemoKeyExtension = REPLACE(STR(@COUNT,2),' ','0') 
        WHERE CURRENT OF MEM_Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM MEM_Cursor 
    END

CLOSE MEM_Cursor
DEALLOCATE MEM_Cursor

Example of desired results:
MemoId                                  MemoKeyExtension
F630A22A-6BAA-4F86-84FB-0823FCAD95A0    95
7BE0E85D-9CA8-4E01-888E-781D5356EDB8    96
5D7BD8F2-5858-4A8F-96B0-E93D44030925    97
9520A24A-5168-41E8-ADFF-429513EB3693    98
5890818B-6EBB-4CD4-94C6-D467679427E5    99
B730FD54-F231-494E-A7F0-E7162F2EDD10    01
578A2457-39DF-41A4-953C-4A3C9E69F394    02
F316C39C-6ACA-4A7C-A401-39518F2EF9A1    03
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: No where clause in update query

Comment: ... and no DBMS tagged

Comment: I didn't put a WHERE clause in the query because I wish to perform the update on ALL records.   Am I missing something I should specify to perform the op on all records?     DBMS = MS Sql

Comment: If you want to update the row just fetched `UPDATE Customer.Memo
        SET MemoKeyExtension = REPLACE(STR(@COUNT,2),' ','0')
        WHERE CURRENT OF Mem_Cursor ;` I advice using set based update instead of cursor.

Comment: There is no need to loop with a cursor here, you can do this in a single set-based update.

Comment: If your counter can only be 1-99 where is the criteria in your existing code to reset the counter? What is the business logic? Your loop starts with Count = 2.

Comment: Thanks Serg, will try that and Serg and Stu - Agreed.   Set based update seems to be the better way from all I've studied but I had trouble thinking of a way to do this as a "set based" operation.  Do you have a suggested change you can offer?

Comment: Since you say you are new to sql I would suggest you forget that cursors and while loops exist. They are not needed for nearly everything outside of a few administrative tasks and perhaps sending emails.

Comment: As for how to go about this you need to explain clearly what you are trying to accomplish. Your code makes it look like you are trying to replace all numbers with spaces....or maybe 0's....or....

Comment: Serg, thanks.  I didn't notice my mistake.   Tried it so many times I grabbed the wrong group of code but I do need to load the field with 01 to 99.  I'll edit that after I test it.   Same idea, but was using If < 99 Else to set the counter.

Comment: Ok, this code is working so I found the issue but it's very slow (as expected) so I'd still like to know how to do this as a set type operation.   As for the business logic, it's too involved to outline here because of a legacy data interface etc.   This is simply being done to solve an immediate problem between the systems.

Comment: By business logic we don't care about all the reasons why, what is important is what you want to happen to the data. Do you just want to assign the number 1 - 99? What happens when you exceed 99? Is there some logic for what order to assign the numeric values?

Comment: Hi Sean, Yes, that's all we need.   Set 01 to 99 and then start again at 01 up to 99 as I showed in the updated question.   Seems too simple I know.   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly guessing here since we have no table definitions to work with. If this doesn't work it should be really close.

```
with MyNumbers as
(
    select NewVal = right('0' + convert(varchar(2), ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) % 99), 2)
        , MemoId
    from Customer.Memo m
)
update m
set MemoKeyExtension = case when NewVal = '00' then '99' else n.NewVal end
from Customer.Memo m
join MyNumbers n on n.MemoId = m.MemoId
```